# Date Validation from other Date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 2 Dates, which is Date From and Date To. My question is, for example if I select in Date From OCT 2,2015 that Date To must be in OCT 3,2015 and above. What Javascript function or Jquery and etc will I use?

Here's my code

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="from" class="control-label col-xs-4"><p class="left">From</p></label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
 <input type="date" value="<?php echo date ('M-d-Y'); ?>" style="width:340px; height:30px;" name="from" required/>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="to" class="control-label col-xs-4"><p class="left">To</p></label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
<input type="date" value="<?php echo date ('M-d-Y'); ?>" style="width:340px; height:30px;" name="to" required />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the max and min properties.

```
$("#from").change(function(){
    $("#to").attr("min",$(this).val());
});

$("#to").change(function(){
    $("#from").attr("max",$(this).val());
});
```